# JQuery scrollTop Function Not Working Onclick a Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want when I click on a tag its scroll me down to `mydiv` with animation I tried but my code didn't work please check this and help me out

```
<a id="myButton" >CLICK ME</a>
<div class="oneDiv">yyy</div>
<div id="mydiv">xxx</div>

.oneDiv {
    background-color:orange;
    height:800px;
    width:100%;
}
#mydiv {
    background-color:green;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
}

$(function)(){
      $("#myButton").on("click", function(){
        $("html body").animate({"scrollTop":$("#mydiv").offset().top},1000);
        return false;
      });
    });
```

Comment: `scrollTop` is not a `css` prop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error near `$(function)(){` There should not have any closing parenthesis after `function` keyword. Following code is working.

```
$(function(){
  $("#myButton").on("click", function(){
    $("html body").animate({"scrollTop":$("#mydiv").offset().top},1000);
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: it happens! In that case browser console helps a lot.

Comment: how to set stop point it scroll down but i want it to stop at certain point of #mydiv